# Django Inline Admin delete missing

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is my admin.py

```
class BooksInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 2
    max_num = 4

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj):
        return True

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=("name", "phone")
    inlines = [BooksInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

In admin the auto generated inlines are missing "delete". If I add one by clicking "add another" It is having delete button. why is it so? How can i enable delete for all the inline forms. (I am using django 1.6)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The extra=2 means you always see at least 2 inlines for this model,
So delete button is removed, try changing the extra value